# How much more does a recommendation letter from alumni help in PhD admissions?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, alumni

Imagine a case where I wish to apply for MIT. I happened to work with a young assistant professor who finished her PhD in MIT. How much will her good words weigh in recommending me to MIT PhD program?

I am asking this because I am facing a choice in asking for recommendations:

- A recommendation letter from a more experienced full professor OR
- One from a young assistant professor who just came back from MIT?

I understand that what matters most is whether the professor knows me well or not. But for them two, I think they understand me roughly the same.

Comment: Why not get recommendations from both?

Comment: @Damien oh the thing is that I have already had two other references from 2 professors who even know me better. So only one slot left...

Comment: @perfectionm1ng well once you aquired both you can still choose which one to send in, right? probably doesn't hurt to send in 4 instead of 3 anyway.

Comment: Oh? I heard that the letters would not come to me, they would directly be sent to the school from the professor. I heard that most of the professors would prefer not to disclose the contents to the students.

Comment: @T.F.  also, say if a school requires only 3 and states that "please do not send in anything that is extra to our requirements", I suppose it to be bad to violate the limit...

Comment: @perfectionm1ng, ok thanks for clearing that up, I wasn't that familiar with the american system.

Comment: @T.F. It's a school-by-school thing, and in some cases even department by department.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree with Damien's answer for the specific case of your question. A graduate of the department, who knows you very well and can write a good letter of recommendation, is worth just as much as the "big name," because she is familiar with the department as it is currently operating, and would be able to place your work in context of people also known in the department. So, for the specific case of applying to a school that is someone else's alma mater, I would say go for it, with a caveat.

That caveat is that if a person is not able of writing a good letter of recommendation, then you shouldn't use it. A bad letter will not help you at all. If you have a career services office or academic counselor who can help you sort through which letters are most suitable for graduate school applications, that will help you make the decision.

Comment: But AFAIK the recommendation letters will not come to my eyes. I heard that most of the professors would prefer to send the letter out directly to the schools that I apply for. Is that true?

Comment: You would ask your letter writers to send a copy to the career center/advisor. The advisor reviews them, and makes recommendations on how to use them, without violating confidentiality.

Answer (score 2):

As both the academics know you the same, I would obtain a reference from the more experienced full professor for your application and a reference from the new assistant professor for your records/supplementary notes.

I have found that you can never have to many references/recommendation letters, but strategically use them for what you are applying for wisely. However, use the recommendation letter only if their specialisations are the same or are similar to what you are applying for.

Comment: Except that no professor (at least in the US) would give _you_ a recommendation letter for _you_.  Letters are sent directly to the requesting institution, usually with the understanding that the recommendee will never be allowed to read them.

Comment: @JeffE apologies then, as this has been my experience.

Comment: @JeffE: In the rest of the world, this is decidedly _not_ necessarily true; I've seen instructions for PhD fellowships explicitly tell candidates to send everything as one PDF—letters of recommendation included!